# Avoid overwriting GAE version

Tags: google-app-engine

When deploying appengine application one has to specify version. If by mistake I don't update it when pushing new code I may loose some state.

Is there a way to minimize this risk (e.g. fail unless `--force` is specified)

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the risk by wrapping the deploy process in a script that enforces your particular version management policies.

"Always bump the version" is a policy that's easy to enforce if you're working solo. That's not the default because many folks push simple bug fixes (e.g., CSS changes, wording in templates) under the same version, where they'll "roll out" as old instances naturally die off and new instances (with fixed code) take their place.